# GET will not passed

Tags: php, html, input, get

I have a strange problem. The GET parameters will not passed.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <?php
        var_dump($_GET);
        var_dump($_POST);
        ?>
        <form action="test.php?ds=1" method="GET">
                    <input type="text">
                    <input type="submit">
                </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

If the method is 'GET' the form jumps to 'test.php' without params.
Not even to 'test.php?ds=1'... Nothing will be passed. 
If i change the method to 'POST' will the form jump to 'test.php?ds=1' but still passes no input.

Comment: Your are missing input name. Please assign name attribute for your input like `<input type="text" name='first_field' />`

Comment: Thank you. That's it. :(

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to give your input a `name` in order to be passed.
Best would be to change to `"POST"` and add `"ds"` as hidden input.

```
<form action="test.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="foo">
    <input type="submit">
    <input type="hidden" name="ds" value="1">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works. I forgot 'name'... :(